# scale up entire div

Tags: html, css, scale, background-size

I was wondering if it’s possible to scale up the percentage of a div as well as its contents?

The game I'm building is pixel-based, so I cannot use percentages inside the *gameContainer* (The background images would also need to scale)

Here's a demo of what I'm trying to achieve      http://codepen.io/friendlygiraffe/pen/MKwjNE

```
<div id="gameContainer">
<div id="scene2">
        <div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>           
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS transforms to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure which `div` requires `scaling`, but you can use the `transform: scale();` property in the CSS of the item that requires scaling.

Such as:

```
#box2 {
    top : 80px;
      position: absolute;
      background-position: center; 
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("http://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/main_logo.jpeg");
    width: 200px; 
    height: 100px;
  transform: scale(2)
}
```

This doubles the scale of the contents in your box2 div. Then respond accordingly to the new value(s).

Example:  [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wrvoyd)

Comment: That's handy, the x, y cordinates in the javascript seem to scale too, but is there a way to make the scale() property responsive to the window?